# showing toastr after checking if the password and user name is correct from database

Tags: php, mysql, toastr

as a practice i made a log in form and linked it with a MySQL database and am trying to show a toastr according to to the result that is if the username and password are correct or not so when the input fields are empty it's showing the error toaster but when i add any thing in the fields it always shows the success toastr i don't know how to fix that

here is my html code

```
 <form class="sing_in_form " method="POST" action="#">
                <input id="email" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Email">
                <input id="password" type="text" name="password" placeholder="password">
                <!--log in button-->
                <button type="submit" id="btn" name="submit " value="LOGIN" class="btn-login">Sign In</button>
                <p class="sign_up">Don't have account? <a href="#">Sign up</a></p>

            </form>
```

php

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){ //username from the form
$uname=$_POST['username'];//username from the form
$pass_word=$_POST['password'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM `loginform2` WHERE user='".$uname."' And Pass='".$pass_word."' limit 1";

$result= $con->query($sql);
```

}

and my js code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn").click(function(){
var name = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'username='+ name + '&password='+ password;
if(name==''||password=='')
{
toastr.error("fill the feilds");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "login(2).php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(){
toastr.success("logged in");
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I understand but for now i only need a way to show a toastr after checking if the password and username are correct or not can you guide me with that

Comment: You're not returning anything from the PHP to indicate the success or failure of the login. The AJAX always succeeds and therefore will always show your success toastr.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  how can i return the vlaues from the php and check them in tha AJAX to show the right toastr, is their any example ?

Comment: There are tons of [tutorials](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

Put `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) ===1 {echo 1};`   after `$result= $con->query($sql);`

And then edit your ajax request as

```
success: function(data){
if(data ==1){
toastr.success("logged in");
}else{
//error message goes here
}
}
```

Comment: This might work unfortunately I can’t try it right now so I’ll hold until tomorrow to check with it